# Capacity of channels: Why do we need Blahut-Arimoto algorithms?

Tags: information-theory

The capacity of a noisy channel $\mathcal{E}_{X\rightarrow Y}$, where the channel is given as a conditional probability distribution $p(y|x)$, is

$$C = \max_{p_X}I(X:Y),$$

where $I(X:Y)$ is the mutual information and $p_X$ is the input probability distribution. This optimization problem is concave. The [Blahut-Arimoto algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blahut%E2%80%93Arimoto_algorithm) is commonly used to find the solution of this optimization problem.

My question is, why was this algorithm developed? Since the problem is a convex optimization problem, why can we not use standard methods such as gradient descent to solve it? Is it that the Blahut-Arimoto algorithm is more efficient or something else? I have read the original paper of Arimoto but it doesn't compare their method to standard convex optimization problem techniques.

Comment: Mutual information is neither convex nor concave in the joint distribution. See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1401808/is-mutual-information-convex-in-the-joint-distribution) on [math.se].

Comment: @YuvalFilmus we only maximize over $p(x)$ (the input distribution), not $p(x,y)$ (the joint distribution). As mentioned in that question, "It is well known that, for fixed $p(y|x)$, mutual information is a concave function of $p(x)$ (e.g. see Theorem 2.7.4 in Cover & Thomas)". The channel is given to us and we only optimize over all possible input distributions to the channel. Does that make sense or did I misunderstand you?

Comment: Cover & Thomas (Elements of information theory) mention several algorithms for computing channel capacity: constrained maximization using the KKT conditions; Frank-Wolfe; and Arimoto–Blahut. Perhaps Blahut–Arimoto is more efficient. They only bother describing the algorithm in detail in the context of rate-distortion theory, so perhaps it's more important there, and for channel capacity other algorithms could indeed be used.